# asp.net error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to retrieve data from a table in sql server called hotel using select WHERE statement and I get the above error. Can anyone help?

```
SqlConnection cnn = new
        SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ToString());
cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RoomsAvailable FROM Hotel WHERE HotelName = '" + 
                    this.DropDownList1.Text + "'";
cmd.Connection = cnn;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
da.SelectCommand = cmd;
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds, "Hotel");
SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da);
DataRow dsRow = null;
foreach (DataRow dsRow_loopVariable in ds.Tables["Hotel"].Rows)
{
    dsRow = dsRow_loopVariable;
    //This line is where the error comes in.
    this.txtHotel.Text = (dsRow["RoomsAvailable"]);
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `dsRow["RoomsAvailable"].ToString()` ?

Comment: Change `dsRow["RoomsAvailable"]` to `dsRow["RoomsAvailable"].ToString()`

Answer (score 9):

Change

```
this.txtHotel.Text = (dsRow["RoomsAvailable"]);
```

To

```
this.txtHotel.Text = (dsRow["RoomsAvailable"].ToString());
```

Comment: Thank you, Habib. I encountered this issue while converting from ASP Classic to VB.NET to C#. Everything worked well in the three conversations until I got to this one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Or change to

```
this.txtHotel.Text = dsRow["RoomsAvailable"] as string;
```

and you won't get an exception if the value is null.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Code

```
 this.txtHotel.Text = Convert.ToString (dsRow["RoomsAvailable"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

`dsRow["RoomsAvailable"]` Is an object of type `DataRow`, if you want the String value you need to call ToString():

```
this.txtHotel.Text = (dsRow["RoomsAvailable"].ToString());
```

[Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Well i saw this code

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT RoomsAvailable FROM Hotel WHERE HotelName = '" + 
                    this.DropDownList1.Text + "'";
```

and `this.DropDownList1.Text` will fetch you selected value not text .
just have you given `HotelNames` as `dropdown` values ?

and for error 
 Try

```
Convert.ToString(dsRow ["RoomsAvailable"]);
```